# Add an additional property when querying database using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I'm using Repository pattern to take all record from the database :

```
var rows = DocumentsRepository.All();
```

However I want to add one additional property. `Documents` table has column `Date` of type datetime and I want to keep the date in separate property. Something like :

```
new {DocumentDate = d.Date.Date}
```

It's just an example to get bette idea of what I want to accomplish. I just guess that I'm gonna need anonymous objects for this job. But not sure how to implement it and also - just to be as clear as possible - I want to be able to use all my other properties and this one along with those that are originally part of the entity.

Comment: Can you edit `Document` class?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. It's database first approach - my first time, not sure what exactly I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to transfer more data over the network. You already have `Date`, so you can just define `DocumentDate` property on your document entity class with getter only (it will not be persisted):

```
   public DateTime DocumentDate 
   { 
       get { return Date.Date; } 
   }
```

Comment: You mean to add it as not mapped property?

Comment: @Leron exactly, it will calculate date based on data from other property

Comment: Good idea, but the feasibility depends on how the code was generated (if generated): is the class partial? in case of EF, overwriting `OnModelCreating` and explicitly ignoring the property could also be required.

Comment: Can I do it with database first approach? Before this project I worked with code first and we used Not Mapped properties but I'm not sure about database first though.

Comment: @Leron usually your generated classes are partial, so you can just create another file with same document partial class and add this property. If entity will be regenerated, it will not affect your code